# Determining decibel level of line-in audio

Tags: linux, audio

Is there a way (via the command line) to output the decibel level of the audio coming into the soundcard's line-in jack? I want to run a script if the volume/intensity of the audio coming into line-in exceeds a certain threshold.

I've checked the files and sub-directories in /proc/asound and have played with the alsa/a* tools a bit, but I haven't found anything promising.

Any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Try rec, included in sox package, with the silence filter. You can determine a level and duration to start and stop a record. Then, you can use it as a trigger to continue the script.

There is a very good link: http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/

Regards,

Comment: Hi @neogurb, welcome to SuperUser. Not totally sure you would want to spend too much time answering 2 year old questions though ;)

Comment: @JulianKnight I disagree, (one of) the point(s) of SO is to maintain an archive of information.  It's not just meant to help the op, but also future visitors (such as myself).  neo: I haven't tried it yet (will let you know), but thank you for the info.  I have the same goal as fsmaniac

Answer (score 2):

Generically, no. The data recorded is a relative value (relative to the maximum the setup will record, which varies by mic, sound card, and other factors).

If you have another piece of equipment by which you can calibrate the values output by the sound card then you can figure it out (again, for a particular setup). But without this external reference there's no way to know.

Comment: That makes sense.  Given that, is there a command-line program that will tell me if there is audio coming into the line-in jack, regardless of strength/decibel level/volume?

At the end of the day, the decibel level isn't as important - simply knowing whether or not there is a signal on the line is.

Answer (score 1):

you may try something like this:

```
/usr/bin/arecord -L # figure out what device to use

/usr/bin/arecord -d 1 --device plughw:CARD=HD1,DEV=0 -t wav | sox -t .wav - -n stats 2>&1 | awk '/RMS lev dB/{print $4}'
```

Comment: Can you share what these commands are doing? Not all users here has technical knowledge, so advising what these commands doing is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the reputation to comment, but I figured I would outline exactly what @pez answer does:

```bash
/usr/bin/arecord -L # figure out what device to use
```

This should produce a series of things that look like `plughw:CARD=HD1,DEV=0`.

I've found that `hw:0` is often enough, especially if you're using some kind of Single Board Computer.

```bash
/usr/bin/arecord -d 1 --device plughw:CARD=HD1,DEV=0 -t wav | sox -t .wav - -n stats 2>&1 | awk '/RMS lev dB/{print $4}'
```

If you ever encounter a command you've never seen, running `man <command_name>` is a good place to start. It will outline what the commands are doing. In this case, the command is `arecord` with the following parameters:

> `-d` <- this sets the duration, in this case 1 second
>
> `--device` <- this sets the device to record from
>
> `-t` <- this sets the output file type

The results from `arecord` (via stdout) are "piped" or fed as the input into a new series of commands (sox in this case) with the `|` vertical pipe character.

`sox` is a command cli utility that performs operations on audio files. In this case, it is being told that the input is a .wav file and to use null for the output `-n`. This is generally used when you want meta information about audio and aren't necessarily interested in playback. Then the `stats` parameter gets us a big wall of text with information about the audio stream.

For some reason we're redirecting `stderr` (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1) with the `>&` operator. Not sure why.

Then pipe (`|`) the output of `sox` into `awk`!

`awk` is kind of a lot if you aren't familiar, but generally it performs operations on text one line at a time. There are several in-built variables to awk, and it has its own syntax. In this case:

```bash
awk '/RMS lev dB/{print $4}'
```

`awk` sets a regular expression with `/.../`, which basically means "if the line I'm processing doesn't match this stream of characters somewhere I'm moving on". Then the body of the `awk` statement comes in, denoted by `{...}`.

The body has a bunch of variables pre-set that tell information about the line such as the number of fields (columns by default, or words separated by a space), and also $0 thru $NF. So this is saying to print only the 4th column from the input text.

---

In the most laymans of terms, that command records a second of audio as a wav file, gets statistics on it with the `sox` command, and then finds the line that has information about decibels and prints out the value.